# printing a board with lines in a 2D char array

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, control-flow

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//prints the board with labels for options.
void print(const char board[3][3])    //function prototype
{
   for(int Row = 0; Row < 3; ++Row)
   {
      for(int Col =0; Col < 3; ++Col)
      {
         cout << board[Row][Col],;
         cout << " | "; 
      }
   }
}

int main()
{      
   int MaxiBoardGrid = 9;

   char board[3][3];

      board[0][0]='A';
      board[0][1]='B';
      board[0][2]='C';
      board[1][0]='D';
      board[1][1]='E';
      board[1][2]='F';
      board[2][0]='G';
      board[2][1]='H';
      board[2][2]='I';

 print(board);

   return 0;     
}


DESIRED OUTPUT;
A|B|C|
------
D|E|F
------
G|H|I
```

I am stuck with having the lines printed and the rows in the format above.

language is C++.

I am new to 2D array and I am trying to use the basic codes I am conversant with to get the board printed. then assign player for my proposed game.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not so much a question about your data (2D array), but about control flow: you're already outputting `|`s after each column, now do the same once per row, after you printed all the columns of that row (i.e. after the inner most for loop). To print a newline output `"\n"` or [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) and you're golden. Take a look at wikibooks [Printing Hello World](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Examples/Hello_world#Printing_Hello_World.21).

Comment: my program only print the letters and i am stuck. guess i have tried all means i know @BeyelerStudios

Comment: yes i did \n.. still did not work @BeyelerStudios

Comment: So I am trying to print the board as stated above, but my code does not print the expected. I need help with resolving it. can you be of help pls.